# Questions about the finite-dimensional normed space of polynomials of degree at most two.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Take $X:=P_2([0,1])$, the polynomials of degree at most $2$ over $[0,1]$ and consider the $2$-norm on this space. For any $x\in X$ we have that,

$$\|x\|_2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Clearly, a basis for this finite-dimensional space is part of the monomial basis, namely, $\{1,x,x^2\}$.

I have two questions. Firstly, what does the following statement mean?

$$\|1\|_2=\|x\|_2=\|x^2\|_2=1$$

Initially I had thought it meant that the norm was equivalent to itself - indeed, equivalence of norms is an equivalence relation, so reflexivity will hold. However, sketching these shapes on the interval $[0,1]$, I found that whilst the latter two, $\|x\|_2=1, \|x^2\|_2=1$ can be "contained" within some $m\|1\|_2,M\|1\|_2$ for fixed $m,M$, it doesn't seem to hold true the other way around, that $\|1\|_2=1$ can be contained within some "stretching" and "shrinking" of $\|x\|_2=1, \|x^2\|_2=1$. As such, I am confused what this statement means and shows.

Secondly, how do I show that,

$$\|2-x+x^2\|_2=\sqrt6\,\text{?}$$

I think I am being thrown off with the use of functions.

Comment: There's nothing that tells us what the $x_i$ symbols mean, and we don't know what $n$ means, so we don't have a clear definition of the norm. Without that, nothing is possible. The usual definition of the L2-norm would involve an integral.

Comment: We have $x\in X=P_2([0,1])$, and I take it that the $x_i$ are the individual components of each $x\in P_2([0,1])$, where every $x \in P_2([0,1])$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of $\{1,x,x^2\}$

Comment: If you were to set $e_1=1, e_2=x$ and $e_3=x^2$ your basis would be $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ which probably looks more familiar.  Your first statement would then be "this is an orthonormal basis".  Your second question could then be written as "find $\| 2e_1 -1e_2 + 1e_3\|_2$" and so $x_1=2, x_2=-1 $ and $x_3=1$ as you've written the norm above.
Sorry I haven't got time to make this a real answer and address your other points though